# RegEx for validating US phone number format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I searched for phone number validation and ended up with below javascript code

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
      phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
      return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
               phone_number.match(/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?(\d{4})$/);
}, "");
```

The above code will return true for below formats

**123-123-1234** or **(123) 123-1234** or **1231231234**

Nw I need to add extension for number for eg

> 123-123-1234 x1234
>
> (123) 123-1234 x1234
>
> 1231231234 x1234

I tried with all my experience with regex (much little :) ) but didn't worked :(

Can you change in my regex to validate **x1234**

Thanks.

Comment: just take off the $ at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an optional match at the end of the regex

```
( x\d{4})?
```

Which will match x followed by digits, that is eg  `x1234` if it is present

- `( x\d{4})?` the quantifier `?` matches zero or one occurence of `( x\d{4})`

The regex can be

```
^\(?(\d{3})\)?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?(\d{4})( x\d{4})?$
```

For example : http://regex101.com/r/sG9qJ6/1

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is already asked with answer as well. Check this [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)